# Sphere texturing and poles

Tags: c#, geometry, directx, mdx, texture-mapping

I use Managed DirectX with C# to texture a sphere (`Mesh.Sphere`).

I use the following code to calculate U and V:

```
CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured[] vertData = (CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured[])tempMesh.VertexBuffer.Lock(0, typeof(CustomVertex.PositionNormalTextured), LockFlags.None, tempMesh.NumberVertices);

for (int i = 0; i < vertData.Length; ++i)
{
    vertData[i].Tu = (float)(1.0 - (double)(0.5f + Math.Atan2(vertData[i].Nz, vertData[i].Nx) / (Math.PI * 2)));
    vertData[i].Tv = (float)(0.5 - Math.Asin(vertData[i].Ny) / Math.PI);
}
```

Now I have the problem, that the poles of the sphere and the poles of my texture (equirectangular projection) does not match.[image: Red points present the poles in my program]

The red points in the picture are the place where the poles of the sphere currently match the texture.

Can someone tell me what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: Just out of intrigue ... what was the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your above code works perfectly provided the sphere is centered at the origin and y is up. I will demonstrate:

Applying the maths with the assumption that poles exist at 0, 1, 0 and 0, -1, 0 gives the following numbers of the poles.

```
 u = 1.0 - (0.5 + (atan2( 0, 0 ) / (2 * PI));
 => u = 1.0 - (0.5 + (0 / (2 * PI));
 => u = 1.0 - 0.5;
 => u = 0.5
 v = 0.5 - (asin( 1 ) / PI)
 => v = 0
```

and

```
 u = 0.5
 v = 0.5 - (asin( -1 ) / PI)
 => v = 0.5 - -0.5
 => v = 1.0
```

Which are the correct values, for u and v, ie (0.5, 0) and (0.5, 1).

If you are using z-up then this WILL give incorrect values (as you would need to swap the y and z over in your calculations) but it still does not give the pole values you are suggesting:

```
 u = 1.0 - (0.5 + (atan2( 1, 0 ) / (2 * PI));
 => u = 1.0 - (0.5 + (PI / (2 * PI)))
 => u = 1.0 - (0.5 + 0.5);
 => u = 0
 v = 0.5 - (asin( 0 ) / PI)
 => v = 0.5 - (0 / PI)
 => v = 0.5
```

and

```
 u = 1.0 - (0.5 + (atan2( -1, 0 ) / (2 * PI));
 => u = 1.0 - (0.5 + (-PI / (2 * PI)))
 => u = 1.0 - (0.5 - 0.5);
 => u = 1.0
 v = 0.5 - (asin( 0 ) / PI)
 => v = 0.5 - (0 / PI)
 => v = 0.5
```

The reason for this is fairly sensible. In the u direction the sphere wraps entirely round.  ie a u of 0 is the same as a u of 1.  This happens entirely in the x-z plane in the equation you have posted (y is not considered for u).  This is why it is divided by 2 * pi or the number of radians in a full circle.  The v direction does not wrap around.  In fact it only applies to half the range and thus a division pi.  You'll note that only y is used in the calculation and, hence, x and z do not affect the v calculation.

Hope that helps.